# spl_autoload_register working on localhost but not online

Tags: php, autoload

I’m trying to dig a little bit in `spl_autoload_register`, and I can’t figure why the same instructions work in localhost and not on a shared server online.

So, I have an index.php file with:

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_register();
    use src\Test;
    $test = new Test;
    $test->show();
?>
```

and a folder named src containing a Test.php file

```
<?php

namespace src;

class Test {
    public function show(){
        echo "Hello from my object";
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine on localhost (WAMP, PHP8.1) but when online (Ionos shared hosting), it seems that the `use src\Test` is not found.

I read the doc, but I still cannot understand why it behaves this way. I know that I could use an custom autoload object, though I didn’t try it yet. My point is, for now to understand why it works on localhost and not online.
Thanks.

Comment: Without a custom callback function, this falls back to `spl_autoload` - quote manual, _"By default it checks all include paths to contain filenames built up **by the lowercase class name** appended by the filename extensions .inc and .php."_ - so your class file _should_ be named `test.php`, not `Test.php`. Windows has a case-insensitive file system, so it will find the file regardless, but Linux file systems are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe ! It works perfectly. I didn’t realized when I read that.

Answer (score 0):

[spl_autoload_register()](https://php.net/spl_autoload_register) can be used to create your own custom auto-loading algorithm, which can be anything you want. But if you don't provide any, as in your case:

> If null, then the default implementation of [spl_autoload()](https://php.net/spl_autoload) will be registered.

Notably, this differs from [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) in that the file name does not match the class name, but its lowercase version:

> By default it checks all include paths to contain filenames built up by the lowercase class name appended by the filename extensions .inc and .php.

FAT32, NTFS... won't see the difference. But Linux filesystems will do.

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro González. Too many infos in the documentation. I missed this one. Thank you for pointing this out. It works perfectly now.